# Choosing a Custom default combo box value in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I got a combobox which  is filled with values from datasource. By default the first value is chosen which is fine but I need to display "Choose country" as the  default combobox text. The user then can choose from the drop down list.

The reason is when the first value from datasource is chosen as the default value the rest of the form field are automatically filled(implemented in selectindexchange method) but I need the form to be empty on load and diplay "Choose country" as Combobox text.

How to do that?

I have my combobox filled

```
CountryDetailsBindingSource.DataSource = CountryCtrl.GetCountryDetails(Id)//this returns an array
 Me.SelectCountry.DataSource = Me.CountryListBindingSource
 Me.SelectCountry.DisplayMember = "CountryName"
 Me.SelectCountry.ValueMember = "ID"
```

Any help is appreciated .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might work if you insert a new value at the start of the array, giving it the CountryName "Choose Country" and ID -1.